# Unity/C#: On/Off Music GUI Button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Almost 90% of the time, my problems are already solved here. But today is my first time asking.

I'm developing a small flappy bird clone, just as a programming challenge. I never used C# or Unity before so...

I have a ON/OFF Button that I wish to "toggle". So far I have this. And It works except for the part of displaying again the 'musicOn' texture and playing again the music.

What is wrong here? Thank you in advance.

```
void OnGUI(){

    toggleMusicButton();

    if(GUI.Button(rect,"", new GUIStyle())){
        music.Pause();
        musicBool = false;
    } 

    if(GUI.Button(rect,"", new GUIStyle())){
        music.Play();
        musicBool = true;
    }

}

void toggleMusicButton(){

    if(musicBool){
        GUI.DrawTexture(rect, musicOn);
    } else {
        GUI.DrawTexture(rect, musicOff);
    }

}
```

Comment: why are you creating two GUI buttons ?

Comment: I just started in C#/Unity. I'm kind of getting the grasp on how things work. My mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have time to test but I believe it's because you are making GUI calls in another method outside OnGUI. I consider OnGUI calls expensive so the less the better.

```
private Texture musicTexture;    

void OnGUI(){

    GUI.DrawTexture(rect, musicTexture);


    if(GUI.Button(rect,"", new GUIStyle())){
        if (musicBool) {
            music.Pause();
            musicBool = false;
            musicTexture = musicOff
        }
        else {
            music.Play();
            musicBool = true;
            musicTexture = musicOn
        }
    } 
}
```

If you are using the DrawTexture just to change the look of the button then do something like this.

Create 2 GUIStyles and set the correct Textures for your button to them

```
public GUIStyle musicOff; //assign a GUIStyle with the correct button image for off
private GUIStyle musicOn; //assign a GUIStyle with the correct button image for on
private GUIStyle musicGUIStyle; //holds GUIStyle being displayed. Assign this a default

void OnGUI(){

    if(GUI.Button(rect,"", musicGUIStyle)){
        if (musicBool) {
            music.Pause();
            musicBool = false;
            musicGUIStyle = musicOff;
        }
        else {
            music.Play();
            musicBool = true;
            musicGUIStyle = musicOn;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. I love this site community. I will upvote as soon as I have reputation.

Comment: Please also mark as the answer when it allows you to.